# How can i access index of foreach when iterating through ko.computed in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, foreach, indexing, paging, knockout.js

i'm building a paged list on the client side with knockout.js and im trying to output the page index with the below code so i get clickable links with numbers so people can switch page.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:Paging">
 <li>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.SetCurrentPage(), text: WHATTOWRITEHERE "></a>
</li>
 </ul>
```

In my viewmodel

```
this.Paging = ko.computed(function () 
{
  return ko.utils.range(1, this.TotalPages);
});
```

Everything works, tried just outputtung text:test and it writes test for each page but i want numbers. So the easiest way is of course to access current index in the foreach and + 1.

How would i be able to do this?

Comment: have you tried "text: this" ?

Comment: i get this error "Message: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side;"  Bindings value: text: this

Comment: Accessing current index : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047713/bind-template-item-to-the-index-of-the-array-in-knockoutjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be with your computed ko. You have not bound it to `this`. So instead of:

```
this.Paging = ko.computed(function ()   
{  
  return ko.utils.range(1, this.TotalPages);  
});
```

.. try ...

```
this.Paging = ko.computed(function ()  
{ 
  return ko.utils.range(1, this.TotalPages); 
}, this);
```

You can then try ColinE suggestion of `text: this`

Comment: tyvm :) forgot to send this as second param to ko.computed on several other places which solved this problems and a few other aswell

Answer (score 2):

When you use `this` in bindings, it will be referencing the window object.  You ought to be using `$data` like this:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.SetCurrentPage(), text: $data"></a>
```

I tested it using this markup and it worked as expected:

```
<!-- returns 12345678910 -->
<div data-bind="foreach: ko.utils.range(1,10)"><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></div>
```